# Why BPMN file from Bizagi is not recognized by BIMP?

Tags: bizagi

I defined a BPMN model in Bizagi, but it is not recongnized by BIMP for simulation. I have the following error "Unable to parse file. BPMN contains one or more processes which do not have a start event.
If you think you have found a bug, then please click here to send an error report including your .bpmn file for investigation."

Comment: The process is well-formed (with start and and events) and validated..